# Prints the m small stack elements without changing the original stack

Tags: algorithm

Please help me with this question: Given a stack A with n keys propose an algorithm that prints the m small stack elements without changing the stack. in time O(mlog(n))

I already know how to get the minimal value in O(1) (creating an auxiliar stack an in each pop() compare with the previous value saved in the auxiliar stack.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which stack operations are allowed ?

Comment: By what miracle can you get the minimum "in O(1)" ?

Comment: "creating an auxiliary stack" -itself is O(n) .The comparison is O(1) and not the building of auxiliary stack.

Comment: CreateStack() – (Enqueue 
(S(Top) 
(S, x(Push – and Pop)
(S(IsEmpty 
S(Size 
S(Pop stack.
"false". I did learn the O(1) (min/max)  from  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAH2VlReNKQ